# Limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^xt-\lfloor t\rfloor dt}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

As shown in the title, what is the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^xt-\lfloor t\rfloor \mathrm{d}t}{x}$?

Both numerator and donominator goes to infinity as $x\to\infty$ but the numerator is not always differentiable on $[0,\infty)$, so I think we can't use L'Hopital's Rule?  I think the answer should be that the limit DNE but how do we prove that?

Comment: You can directly compute that integral and then use it to compute the limit

Comment: @Luca.b What do you mean?

Comment: $\int_0^xt-\lfloor t\rfloor dt=\frac {\lfloor x\rfloor}{2}+\int_0^{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}t dt$

Comment: @Luca.b Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $n:=\lfloor x\rfloor,\,r:=\{x\}$ so $\int_0^x(t-\lfloor t\rfloor)dt=\tfrac12n+\int_0^rydy=\tfrac12(n+r^2)$, so the limit is squeezed between those of $\frac{n}{2(n+r)}$ and $\frac{n+r}{2(n+r)}=\frac12$, and is $\frac12$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First, observe that $f(t)=t-\lfloor t\rfloor$ is periodic and bounded:
\begin{align}
f(t) &= f(t+1)\\
\lvert f(t)\rvert &\le 1\ \forall t
\end{align}

Therefore, the primitive of $f$ can be expressed as
$$F(x) = ax + B(x)$$
where $a$ is the average value of $f$ over a period, and $B$ is a periodic and bounded function.

$$\therefore\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ax+B(x)}{x}$$

Since $B$ is bounded, it is clear that this limit is just equal to $a$, which is given by
$$a = \int_0^1 f(t)\mathrm{d}t = \tfrac{1}{2}$$